# How to process multiple files with PostCSS & laravel mix?

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, postcss

I have some CSS files that I want to process with PostCSS, but my current config is throwing an error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\OpenServer\domains\test.loc\public\css\styles.css' in 'D:\OpenServer\domains\test.loc'

I believe PostCSS starts looking for the input file before it is generated. How do I make laravel mix wait for styles.css to be generated?

Here is my webpack config:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.styles([
    'resources/css/app.css',
    'resources/css/animations.css',
    'resources/css/header.css',
    'resources/css/mobile-menu.css',
    'resources/css/books-scroll.css',
    'resources/css/books-list.css',
    'resources/css/footer.css'
], 'public/css/styles.css');
mix.postCss('public/css/styles.css', 'public/css/styles.css', [
    require('autoprefixer') ({
        overrideBrowserslist: ['> 0.4%', 'last 6 versions', 'Firefox >= 20', 'Android >= 4', 'iOS >=7']
    })
]);
```

**EDIT**: If I run this script a second time, the error goes away, but the result in styles.css will always be my original CSS, but merged into one file. For PostCSS to process the file, I need to manually comment out the mix.styles() method and run the script again.

**EDIT 2**: The only solution that worked for me was creating an additional css file with all the other files manually imported in using @import. It's not the prettiest solution, but it works.

*CSS*

```css
@import "./styles/header.css";
@import "./styles/footer.css";
```

*webpack.mix.js*

```js
mix.postCss('resources/css/additional.css', 'public/css/styles.css', [
    require('autoprefixer') ({
        overrideBrowserslist: ['> 0.4%', 'last 6 versions', 'Firefox >= 20', 'Android >= 4', 'iOS >=7']
    })
]);
```